# How can I access a repository globally in loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback4

I used loopback 4 to bootstrap my API application and developed some parts of it.
Now I'm trying to access repositories outside the controllers and tried everything I could but didn't help. None of my searches did too. For example I have a controller in which I can access repo such way.

```
constructor(
@repository(UserRepository) public userRepository: UserRepository){}
```

But if it isn't a controller it won't work and I found out  I had a wrong understanding about @repository and @inject decorators.

**My Case:**
I want to run a cron-job to perform an update operation on database every day at a specific time.
The thing is I think I should create a service or something like that to expose database operations so it can be accessible anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're trying to tackle comes down to dependency injection. It's described at https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Dependency-injection.html but that article does not explain how to create a separate class that works with dependency injection.

In short, in order to perform the dependency injection through decorators, LoopBack needs to be the one to construct the class you're writing, so that it can pick what you need from its Context. So, instead of writing `new ClassSomething`, it has to be `@inject(ClassSomething)` or `@service(ClassSomething)`, and those decorators only work in a class also instantiated by LoopBack. In other words, your class has to be in the "call tree" from the original application class (`application.ts`) for dependency injection to work.

The easiest way to do what you want to do is to use LoopBack's Cron component: see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Running-cron-jobs.html. You could convert your class to a `CronJob` if it has no other purpose, or let the `CronJob` create an instance of your class. In the latter case, you need to bind your class to the application Context so that the `CronJob` can access it through decorators. You can do so in two ways:

- Convert your class to a Service (see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Service.html and https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Service-generator.html). If what your class does can be thought of as a service, this is the way to go.
  Inject your class with: `@service(MyServiceClass) myService: MyServiceClass`
- Directly bind your class to the application context, in `application.ts`:
  `this.bind('MyClass').toClass(MyClass);`
  Inject your class with: `@inject(MyClass) myClass: MyClass`

The latter option is not best practice AFAIU as it does not adhere to IoC-principles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) - basically, by hard-coding the class binding in the application class, it is not exactly modular. When your class is converted to a service (and placed in `src/services`), it will automatically be added to the Context, meaning you can inject it everywhere using `@service()`.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same(cron word). I couldn't find any solution still in the documentation. But still, I have achieved this in this way.

1. just call repository as like class with dependency in it. do this in your index.ts file where you start the application.

   ```
   async function startCronJobs(app: SawLoopbackApplication) {
     const userRepo = app.repository(UserRepository);
     const userRepoInstance = await userRepo.getValue(app);
     const cron = new CronComponent(userInstance);

     //---- Exicute your cron here
     new CronJob('0 6 * * *', function () {
          cron.sendMorningMail()
        }).start();

     //---- Exicute your Second Cron
     new CronJob('0 8 * * 1', function () {
        cron.weeklyAppraisalsToAgent()
      }).start();
    }
   ```
2. call your cron in the functional component and execute a raw query to get the details from DB etc...

   ```
   import {MysqlDataSource} from '../../datasources'
   const query = `select * from accounts where IP="${ipAddress}" ORDER By 
   createdAt DESC Limit 1`
   const dataSource = new MysqlDataSource()
   const accountDetails = await dataSource.execute(query)
   console.log(accountDetails)
   ```
3. instead of a raw query. call your repository from the function component below

   ```
     import {MysqlDataSource} from '../datasources'
     import {ContactUsUserDetailsRepository} from '../repositories'
     const contactUsUserDetailsRepository = new ContactUsUserDetailsRepository(new MysqlDataSource)
      function saveContactDetails(){
          const payload={UID:"Unique ID",name:"Durai"}
          await contactUsUserDetailsRepository.create(payload)
       }
   ```

I would prefer **2** because, if you have a lot of imports in your cron class constractor you need to pass all of them while calling a function like in the **3rd** point.

Have fun:)